# RL - Stable Baselines with PyTorch- DQN: Why does the CustomModel not learn?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I want to use the stable baseline RL implementation and use a custom model. I simplified my case. I have three questions:

- Why doesn't it learn to predict 2? Depending on the initialization it predicts 4, 7, 3, ...
- I would assume that CustomCombinedExtractor produces in the forward-pass the final discrete prediction. So this would be dimension 10. But instead stable baselines requires it to output a 64 dim vector. Why is that? Is there a further model applied afterwards? How can I deactivate that?
- What sensible options do we have for: "lr_schedule"?

Here the code:

```
import gym
from gym import spaces
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.dqn import MultiInputPolicy
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch


class CustomEnv(gym.Env):
    """Custom Environment that follows gym interface"""
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(10)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Dict({
            "vector1": spaces.Box(low=0, high=10, shape=(10,), dtype=np.float32),
            "vector2": spaces.Box(low=0, high=10, shape=(10,), dtype=np.float32)
        })

    def obs(self):
        return dict({
            "vector1": 5*np.ones(10),
            "vector2": 5*np.ones(10)})

    def step(self, action):
        if action == 2:
            reward = 20
        else:
            reward = 0
        return self.obs(), reward, False, dict({})

    def reset(self):
        return self.obs()

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        return None

    def close(self):
        pass

env = CustomEnv()

class CustomCombinedExtractor(MultiInputPolicy):
    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space, lr_schedule):
        super().__init__(observation_space, action_space, lr_schedule)

        extractors = {}

        total_concat_size = 0
        for key, subspace in observation_space.spaces.items():
            elif key == "vector"1:
                extractors[key] = nn.Linear(subspace.shape[0], 64)
                total_concat_size += 64
            elif key == "vector2":
                extractors[key] = nn.Linear(subspace.shape[0], 64)
                total_concat_size += 64

        self.extractors = nn.ModuleDict(extractors)
        self._features_dim = 1
        self.features_dim = 1

    def forward(self, observations):
        encoded_tensor_list = []

        x = self.extractors["vector"](observations["vector"])
        return x.T


def lr_schedule(x): return 1/x
policy_kwargs = dict(
    features_extractor_class=CustomCombinedExtractor,
    features_extractor_kwargs=dict(
        action_space=spaces.Discrete(10), lr_schedule=lr_schedule),
)

model = DQN(MultiInputPolicy, env, verbose=1,
            buffer_size=1000, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs)

model.learn(total_timesteps=25000)
model.save("ppo_cartpole")

del model  # remove to demonstrate saving and loading

model = DQN.load("ppo_cartpole")

obs = env.reset()
while True:
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    print(action)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just checked your code again and saw the learning rate schedule:
You are passing a function that is 1/x. x will be the progress_remaining that goes from 1.0 .. 0 as learning progresses. So at the end you might have an issue with div/0 here (not sure though if progress_remaining actually hits 0.0 at the end or terminates just before).
But the bigger problem is: Did you check which learning rate values you are actually using with this function? At start of learning it is 1/1 = 1. At end of learning it will grow to infinity!! Normal learning rates are in the range of 5e-5 .. 3e-3. So your learning rates are at least 2 orders of magnitude too high! 1/x is not a sensible function in this regard! (unless at least you change it to something like 1/(1-x)*m, where m scales the resulting values sufficiently small. I guess this is what you had in mind with 1/x). I'd recommend you start with a constant standard learning rate e.g. 1e-4 and do the lr schedules once this works.

Another thing that is really odd with your code is that the Obs is constant. It might just be prevented from learning anything if whatever of the 10 actions it takes leads to zero change in the observation! It can get the reward on action==2, but it can't really pick anything up from a state-action-reward relationship in your example because there is none.
Another possible problem is that your episode (game) never ends! You always return done=False on every step(). It would be good to wrap up an episode / game at some point with done=True in order to help the model evaluate its post-game performance and learn from it.
(Another minor suggestion is that you should normalize your Observations to -1,+1 (centered around 0) according to documentation - but this should not be the key problem here.)

In your case it would probably make more sense to just combine & flatten the two vectors into a list / 1d-array so you don't need to create the CustomCombinedExtractor class at all.

Concerning Schedules docu check this link for linear schedule (reducing from initial value to 0 over all training steps):
https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/examples.html?highlight=Linear%20schedule#learning-rate-schedule

For further ideas check this link: https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/common/schedules.html

If you want to play with sb3, check this repo: https://github.com/DLR-RM/rl-baselines3-zoo
You will also find tuned hyperparameters there for different models.